# PHP imap Authentication fails on ubuntu but works on Windows

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, imap, email, php-imap

I have a same code on both servers Windows and Ubuntu. Windows' code works fine. it connects to email box and does all the operations. But the same code on Ubuntu server is showing Authentication error.

```
$this->econn = imap_open("{xxxxxx:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "xxxx@xxxx.xx", "xxxxxxx", NULL, 1,
                    array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI') ) or 
               die(var_dump(imap_errors()));
```

Now I was searching for solution and found this suggestion which I tried

```
 array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN')
```

but still no luck.

I haven't changed anything on code. I have even tried copy and pasting code from windows to ubuntu and still have same issue.

The only thing I have done on ubuntu server is updating my server and php. imap is still installed on ubuntu. So I have no idea whats the reason behind this error.

Update: 
Here is the error I am getting.

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {xxxxxxxxxx:xxx/imap/ssl}INBOX in /xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx.php on line 39
```

On var_dump(imap_errors())

```
array (size=1)
0 => string 'Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed.' (length=57)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check mail server logs? Also will be helpful to post the error you've got from the script itself.

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with an error which I am getting.